# Adding style sheets or something similar to control iOS app UI?

Tags: ios, uikit, stylesheet

So I have done some work with Qt, and they have a [QStyleSheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/stylesheet.html) class where you can apply a style string to control the style of UI elements similar to CSS style sheets. Is there anything like this that I could use for UIKit? I've tried searching, but I only find references to style sheets for UIWebView.

In Qt you might do something like this:

```
objectPointer->setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: red; color: white;}");
```

Comment: Ambiguous: do you mean Apple's UIKit framework on iOS, or the open source uikit for developing web interfaces? http://getuikit.com/  If you mean iOS UIKit, why would you want to diverge from the platform's style?  That is what the Qt stylesheet is best for, to make an app conform to the platform style.

Answer (score 0):

check nimbuskit or UISS or NUI projects. all of them provide such CSS stylings for your views.